# Content Scroll Over Background - Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have the following CSS for a div that spends 100% of the viewport.

```
.content
{
background-image: url('../images/content_bg.png');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
color: white;
}
```

On desktop this works fine. Even when I scaled down the desktop window to mobile sized it stills looks as I want it to.

However, both on android and iPhone the background is scaled to entire size of the div, which greatly distorts it.

I want it to stay proportionate, but have the content scroll over it.

I also tried removing background-size: cover. This makes it look how I want it to, but it doesn't cover the div obviously, so I have a bunch of content that has spilled out.

I'm running a newer android and iPhone with the most recent updates, which I believe supports the fixed backgrounds, so I'm at a loss as to what is wrong. When I remove fixed the desktop version looks exactly like it does on mobile. So it appears for some reason that is the issue that fixed isn't being applied to mobile.

Comment: Try this `background-size:100% 100%;`

Comment: That's give a similar issue to the cover, on my mobile devices it's badly distorting the image.

Comment: Looks like it can't be done http://stackoverflow.com/q/21786272/483779