# CSS contain + position partially off-screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fit a background image, using the css `background-size: contain;` properties, but position it partially off-screen. I have an image with a transparrent part and I would like to be able to manipulate the "fill", so I thought moving a background image into view would be a good way to achieve this:

```
.bottle {
    background-image: res://bottle_fill;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50% 30%;
}
```

But it seems that with the contain parameter, the image can't "overspill" from the div? I tried adding `overflow: hidden` but it didn't help. How can I achieve this? A JavaScript solution is fine if there isn't a css way.

## Update:

https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj/ here is a JSFiddle - try to get the smiley face half on, half off the screen, whilst it is sized `contain`. As noted by some of the comments, I know this is a slightly strange thing to want to do, but the background image must be the same size as the contents of the div (and `<image>` sized with the contain parameter) the raw files are the same size, hence if they both use contain, they will come out the same size and I can set `x align` to be center and then use `y align` to control how much of the bottle is full.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with this problem?

Comment: This sort of thing is discussed in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786272/css-background-size-cover-background-attachment-fixed-clipping-background-im).

Comment: @Bodzio Sure, [https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj/](https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj) - try to get the smiley face half on, half off the screen

Comment: @Ouroborus I may have misunderstood that question, but I think they are trying to avoid clipping, which is what I am after?

Comment: the goal of this question isnt clear in my opinion, i didnt understand. what is the issue and the expected result on that fiddle?

Comment: @freestock.tk I want to be able to position a background image partially on, partially off screen, so you can only see part of it, whilst using the contain size property

Comment: but this off-screen part is the opposite behavior of the `background-size: contain;` property (where the element always fits 100% inside the container); if you want crop, so youre looking for `background-size:cover;` instead

Comment: @freestock.tk No, I want the size to be dictated by `contain`, as the background image size must be the same as the `<image>` size, so it must have the size `contain`, or a JS equivalent.

Comment: `**contain**Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area`  You can't use contain if you want the background to be bigger than it's container, the entire point of the contain size is to make sure the background fits IN the container

Comment: @GavinThomas I don't want the background image to be bigger than the background, I just want it positioned partially off-screen. So I can gradually move it onto the screen until the bottle is "full" and the background image is positioned in the middle of the div.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj/6/

Comment: @GavinThomas I think that only works if my image is square? In my actual application, I am using rectangles... Also, this needs to be responsive, and % don't seem to work with that approach?

Comment: Not at all. 100vh and 100vw is based on the screen size - if you have a rectangular image, you can just get the ratio right and set the `vh` accordingly.

Comment: @GavinThomas but it stretches images, see https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj/7/

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj/8/

Comment: @GavinThomas but that won't go partially off-screen?

Comment: It will if you set the `background-position:`

Comment: @GavinThomas is there any way for it to work with percentage positions?

Comment: You could just use `vw` positioning? As 1vw = 1% of the screen width, same for 1vh = 1% of screen height.

Comment: @GavinThomas Well I need to act in relation to the height of the image, not the screen, but I guess that by using JS to get the actual height of the image I could then calculate the vh offset? However, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ghhxddnj/11/) JSFiddle isn't getting the element height - `Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null` any ideas? If that can work, then please feel free to post an answer for me to accept

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var image_url = $('#logo').css('background-image'),
    image;

// Remove url() or in case of Chrome url("")
image_url = image_url.match(/^url\("?(.+?)"?\)$/);

if (image_url[1]) {
    image_url = image_url[1];
    image = new Image();

    // just in case it is not already loaded
    image.src = image_url;
    var imgoffset = image.height;
    $('#logo').css('background-position',-imgoffset)
}
```

Source: [How do I get background image size in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery)

**EDIT:** https://jsfiddle.net/ckf55axs/

Comment: Can we do it without JQuery? Also, I don't need to get the background image size, the image tag, which can have a class or id, will be the same size, so if that is simpler.

Comment: So your element isn't going to be a background image, or is your offset being set by a static amount, not dependent on the elements height? I'm lost in what you want now..

Comment: Sorry for being confusing, I have an image of a bottle outline. I want to show the bottle filling up, by moving a background image up behind it. So 1. I need the background image to be the same size as the bottle outline. 2.  need to be able to move the background up and down, to show different bottle fill levels, to do this, I need to know how heigh the bottle outline is. Does that make sense?

Comment: So the BACKGROUND is being defined on how big the element is?

Comment: well yes, but by setting it to cover, or an equivalent, then it will be the right size, but the position WILL be dictated by the size of the foreground image.

Comment: So why not just set the size of the element instead, and have the container wrap to it?

Comment: I am using NativeScript to write a native mobile app, so I don't have access to full html and the container I am using is defined as a grid, which depending on the width to height ratio of the mobile device will change in proportions.