# background-image cover but limited height (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image

Trying to cover the background-image of the #header to fullwidth (no white space) but limited hight. Dont know whats wrong, can you helpf?

http://vintagemaedchen.de/

2nd question:
how can I adjust the post images (.post-img img) so that too big images are cut and not down-scaled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-size:cover;`.  This will scale the background image large as possible so that the background area is completely filled by the background image.

Comment: background-size, as you see is cover. thats why I am a bit confused

Comment: This is because the image itself (http://xn--vintagemdchen-ifb.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Vintage-Blog-Banner.png) has a lot of white around it with the flowers just in the center.  Crop your background image to just be the flowers and it should work.

Comment: have a look at it now. It does sth strange above the image. Cant find a solution :-(

Comment: This is a known issue when combining fixed with cover.  Here is the stackoverflow which discusses the reason behind the issue and JavaScript workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786272/css-background-size-cover-background-attachment-fixed-clipping-background-im