# Multiple divs (some with and without background-attachment: fixed) sharing a background-image / Strange result with background-size property

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, background-size

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bot">
      <div id="one"></div>
      <div id="two"></div>
      <div id="thr"></div>
      <div id="fou"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#top {
    height: 100vh;
}

#bot {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

    #one, #two, #thr, #fou {
        flex: 1;
        background: url('image.jpg');
    }

    #one, #thr {
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

**JS**

```
function whatever() {
    var oneW = one.clientWidth;
    two.style.backgroundPosition = '-' + oneW + 'px 0';
    fou.style.backgroundPosition = '-' + oneW * 3 + 'px 0';
};
```

I have run into a problem. The general effect that I want to create can be achieved with the code above. However, the dimensions of the `background-image` seem to be the dimensions of the actual image file since I have not created and set the `background-size` property, so the image will not be centered and instead is cut off if the browser is smaller than the image itself. I have tried applying `background-size: cover`, but it seems to effect the elements with `background-attachment: fixed` differently than those without that property, and I'm not sure what to do or how I can get around this. **Does anybody know how I can address this particular issue?** Thanks in advance for any solutions, help, or ideas!

**UPDATE**

So, based on information from two pages that ([CSS background-size: cover + background-attachment: fixed clipping background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786272/css-background-size-cover-background-attachment-fixed-clipping-background-im) and http://www.carsonshold.com/2013/02/css-background-sizecover-doesnt-like-fixed-positioning/) I have come across, I have added some JS to adjust the height of the `background-attachment: fixed` `div`s, which kind of solves the problem but not really. Below is the additional JS.

```
function whatever()
{
    ...
    var oneH = one.clientHeight;
    one.style.backgroundSize = 'auto ' + oneH + 'px';
    thr.style.backgroundSize = 'auto ' + oneH + 'px';
};
```

This will align the image perfectly if the browser is full screen or quarter screen, even though `background-size` is set to `cover`, but for whatever reason the image now behaves as if `background-size` is set to `contain`. I'm so confused.

**UPDATE II**

I solved this by manually setting the size of each div to that of window's innerWidth and innerHeight. The code is below in the answer section.

Comment: It might help to include the html as well...

Comment: @JonSG         It has nothing to do with the HTML, but as per your request I've included it anyways.

Comment: @JonSG         I solved the problem by manually setting `div.style.backgroundSize` to `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: Cool, I tried for several hours last night and was not able to come up with anything other than a slew of posts about this issue.

Comment: @JonSG         Yeah, all the articles and posts that I came across were similar, yet different.  Stoked this worked, but there is one issue: the image becomes proportional to the browser size, so if you resize your browser to funny proportions the image also looks funny. A few media queries and or if else statements should do the job, though. Do you mind sharing the articles you came across? Thanks in advance<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually setting the width and height of each `div` so that they correspond to the width and height of the window works.

```
function whatever() {
    ...
    var x = window.innerWidth;
    var y = window.innerHeight;
    one.style.backgroundSize = '' + x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
    two.style.backgroundSize = '' + x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
    thr.style.backgroundSize = '' + x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
    fou.style.backgroundSize = '' + x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
};
```