# How to Scale and Stretch background using CSS

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

How to get a background in CSS to stretch or scale to fill its container size?

I am doing as below

```
body
{ 
    background: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg) no-repeat fixed; 
    background-size: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Whats wrong in this code ?

Comment: You should define your browser-prefixed styles first, but other than that, your CSS should do exactly what you describe.

Comment: That background is scaled to fill the space.

Comment: @Quentin- background is not scaled.. I am not getting what is wrong with this code. :(

Comment: Please stop editing the question....we are trying to help you.

Comment: Is this what you are after - https://jsfiddle.net/2rjf4rum/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D--->Is this compulsory to do following 
html {
  height: 100%;
}

Comment: Do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try This to reset CSS:

```
* {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     border:0;
}

body {
       background: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
       background-size: cover;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply u can do this...

```
body {  
background: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

}

Comment: This would simply have the background fill the width of the element, not scale to fit.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your code is working. Just note that when you apply a `fixed` background position, you take the image out the `dom` pretty much as if it were a fixed image, so if you do:

```
background: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg) no-repeat top left;
background-size: cover;
```

It should work as you hope. I came across this too, may be of help: [CSS background-size: cover + background-attachment: fixed clipping background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786272/css-background-size-cover-background-attachment-fixed-clipping-background-im)

Comment: No idea why this was voted down. It's a valid answer, and fills the container size, in CSS, which is what the OP asked: How to get a background in CSS to stretch or scale to fill its container size?