# background-size: cover; property

Tags: jquery, css, background-size

Whenever the background image changes, I need it to cover the body. I'm using `background-size: cover`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
body {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 60px;
   background-color: #000;
   font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
   background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lECC6eQhnZo/maxresdefault.jpg); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-atachment: fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   transition: background 1s;
```

and here's the jQuery that changes the image:

```
$("body").css("background", objects[newNum].img);
```

the images are stored in an array (objects).

CodePen: http://codepen.io/Chantun/pen/WxXaGy?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your usages of background to background-image. Because it conflicts with background-size.

So for your CSS it would be:

```
body {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 60px;
   background-color: #000;
   font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
   background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lECC6eQhnZo/maxresdefault.jpg); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-atachment: fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   transition: background 1s;
```

And for your JS it should be:

```
$("body").css("background-image", objects[newNum].img);
```

Comment: Thanks! it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

background cover is right work. on default body height: auto. use min-height: 100vh for body. and change margin-top to padding-top.

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/bZjZKA)

Answer (score 1):

Changing `background-attachment` on your codepen to have two t's instead of one does make it work how I think you want it. You can also combine your background rules into shorthand like:

```
background: #000 url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lECC6eQhnZo/maxresdefault.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up!

`background-attachment: fixed` and `background-size: cover` don't play nicely with each other! :(

More detailed explanation about how and why they clash here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23811091

Edit: also your `background-attachment: fixed` is misspelled! :)