# CSS background image - shrink to fit fixed size div

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have the following code at https://jsfiddle.net/ncrcfduz, and a background image at https://s21.postimg.org/iq2mtjaiv/bg_boardwalk.jpg. I need to make the background image rescale to fit in the div, preferred to show most of the "centered" content in the image. The following code only show the top-left corner of the image.

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://s21.postimg.org/iq2mtjaiv/bg_boardwalk.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "centered" content?

Comment: Use background-size: contain instead.

Comment: This is relelvant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786272/css-background-size-cover-background-attachment-fixed-clipping-background-im
with `background-attachment: fixed` image is sized relative to viewport, not containing element.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're looking for `background-size: contain` ([see the MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)), not `cover`. To get your example to work, you'll have to drop the `background-attachment: fixed`. Use `background-position: center` to center the background in your `div`.

```css
.container{
    background: url(https://s21.postimg.org/iq2mtjaiv/bg_boardwalk.jpg) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

### Notes:

- These days you almost certainly don't need the browser prefixes, meaning you can just use `background-size: contain`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility
- If you're using [Autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) (included in many build tools and build setups) it will automatically add any necessary prefixed versions for you, meaning you could do `background-size: contain` even if current versions of the major browsers still required prefixes.
- You can include size in the `background` shorthand property with the syntax `background: <background-position>/<background-size>`. That would look like

```css
.container{
    background: url(https://s21.postimg.org/iq2mtjaiv/bg_boardwalk.jpg) no-repeat center/contain;

    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you should use:

```
.container{
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to replace "fixed" by "center" on your "background" instruction.

Like that:

```
background: url(https://s21.postimg.org/iq2mtjaiv/bg_boardwalk.jpg) no-repeat center;
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ncrcfduz/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.container{
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way. You can set your code like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('your_url') ;background-size: 100% 100%; "> <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick should work but it will not keep the image aspect ratio by default.

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```