# Parallax effect within bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, parallax

Hello guys I'm trying to make simple parallax effect within bootstrap grid system and I've run into a problem. I made two `divs` side by side and I want one `div` to hold static image while other should have parallax effect.

I have a problem with parallax `div` **background-size property** no matter what I try I can't make it to cover my parallax div the way I want it, background image always end up being larger then it should be or not aligned correctly.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<section id="twoImages" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="parallax"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placebear.com/715/470" alt="shoe newspaper">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 50em;
}

#twoImages {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#twoImages .col-md-6 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#twoImages .parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("https://placebear.com/715/470");
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is the codepen so you can better understand my problem https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/VpeBzp

Comment: @AjayBisht Thats the part that basically makes parallax effect

Comment: This may have been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786272/css-background-size-cover-background-attachment-fixed-clipping-background-im

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer

you need to use jquery

check this https://codepen.io/parthjasani/pen/YZwJMq

```
remove 
 background-attachment: fixed; 
from css
```

and add this jquery code

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict()
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop()
  $(".parallax").css({"background-position":"0px "+scroll/2+"px"})
})
```