# BG image on phone is not resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I tried to do this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background: url("http://popidesigns.ro/images/bgtel.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
}
```

With the new picture `@ 1080x1920(normal it was 1920x1080)`
But no change. How can I make the BG Pic visible on the whole phone screen?
(the bg image is that thing above the logo) 
[phone ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWBn5.jpg)

[laptop ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQsEQ.jpg)

Comment: can you describe which language, which version etc...?

Comment: HTML5 and CSS3 .

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23811091/5639232

Answer (score 0):

add `background-size: cover` to fill the container/body

...and make sure the body is at least 100% high by adding

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: body {
  background: url("http://popidesigns.ro/images/bgbgb.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}     did that but still not working

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/KyrvOP

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  body{
  background:url('http://popidesigns.ro/images/bgbgb.png') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  }
}
```

I also added a viewport meta tag in the head of the page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    background: URL("http://popidesigns.ro/images/bgtel.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will make sure that the image doesn't repeat and is centered. The background-size:cover; will ensure that the image will cover the entire screen. width at 100% helps with that.

Comment: Perhaps try explaining *why* this code achieves the effect the OP is looking for?