# Background image looks different on mobile device than on mobile preview in PC browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a background picture of some random apartment for my website and it looks good on PC and on mobile preview on PC(using Firefox Developer Edition).
But when I open it on my iPhone 7 it does not look good, it just shows top left corner of an image.

**This is how it looks on my PC:**
[image: pcimage]

**And this is how it looks on my iPhone 7:**

[image: iphoneimage]

**This is css for div that has that background image:**

```css
#home {
    background: url("../images/seaview/mainpic1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    display: table;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Did you set your viewport?
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: yes I did set it

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786272/css-background-size-cover-background-attachment-fixed-clipping-background-im

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are missing a value for `background-size` and leaving it up to the browser. Just add `cover` to your CSS rule for the background image:

```
background: url("../images/seaview/mainpic1.jpg") no-repeat center center cover;
```

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: background-size: cover; is set

Comment: Sorry I missed that!